# Using separator in column count

Tags: css, column-count

I want to use a separator in every column while using the **column-count** of CSS.

HTML:

```
<ul class="channel_list">
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="7" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 1</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="8" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 2</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="9" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 3</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="6" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 4</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.channel_list{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
.channel_list li{ list-style: none}
```

What i want something like-
[image]

I try:

```
.channel_list li{ border-right: 5px solid red}
```

> Only the border at the right side of the li's but not in the last
>   column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding of the question is correct, you can achieve this using the [`column-rule` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-rule0). It is a shorthand property which comprises of `column-rule-width`, `column-rule-color` and `column-rule-style`. These three long-hand properties work exactly similar to `border-width`, `border-color` and `border-style`. `column-rule-style` supports all values that are supported by `border-style`.

Note that you ***can't produce rounded separators*** (that is, there is no equivalent of `border-radius`).

(*The property [still needs vendor prefixes in all browsers other than IE!](http://caniuse.com/#search=column).*)

```css
.channel_list {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center; /* make the separator look like it is in middle */
  -webkit-column-count: 3;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
  
  /* just for spacing */
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
.channel_list li {
  list-style: none;
}
.channel_list.solid {
  -webkit-column-rule: 5px solid red;
  -moz-column-rule: 5px solid red;
  column-rule: 5px solid red;
}
.channel_list.dashed {
  -webkit-column-rule: thin dashed chocolate;
  -moz-column-rule: thin dashed chocolate;
  column-rule: thin dashed chocolate;
}
.channel_list.dotted {
  -webkit-column-rule: medium dotted rebeccapurple;
  -moz-column-rule: thin dotted rebeccapurple;
  column-rule: thin dotted rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<ul class="channel_list solid">
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="7" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 1</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="8" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 2</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="9" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 3</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="6" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 4</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 5</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="channel_list dashed">
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="7" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 1</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="8" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 2</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="9" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 3</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="6" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 4</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 5</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="channel_list dotted">
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="7" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 1</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="8" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 2</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="9" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 3</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="6" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 4</li>
  <li>
    <input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I make the image by hard drawing, cause i need to set the border middle, but my try goes to right and also the last one. Your guess in right and i need this, but is it possible to make the rule middle???

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get you. Are you saying that the separator should be exactly in the middle (equal space on either side) of the columns and that there should be no separator on the right edge?

Comment: @RivnatNasah: But you ask a good question. Let me see if there is a way to get it in the middle. If I manage to find one, I'll update the answer and ping you :)

Comment: @RivnatNasah: There seems to be no specific property to get the separator in the middle. We can give the `column-gap` but depending on actual width of columns that changes and so line doesn't always remain in the middle. One workaround would be to use `text-align: center` on the `ul` (like in the updated answer).

Comment: Yes, I think about  to do this at the end of your complete answer. I can't seem anything without this.

Answer (score 0):

Use column rule

```
     -webkit-column-rule: 4px outset red; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     -moz-column-rule: 4px outset red; /* Firefox */
     column-rule: 4px outset red;
```

Codepen URL - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jrrGGX for reference

Hope this works for you

Comment: column-rule is the CSS property for the styling(width,style,color) between columns

Comment: Use column gap...for adjusting that the spacing and position the separator to center
 -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;

Comment: I already get my answer that is same strategy.. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternate solution.

```css
.channel_list{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
.channel_list li{ list-style: none;border-right:5px solid red}
.channel_list li:nth-child(n+9){border-right:none} /* selects from the ninth onwards */
```

```html
<ul class="channel_list">
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="7" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 1</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="8" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 2</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="9" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 3</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="6" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 4</li>
    <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 5</li>
      <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 6</li>
      <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 7</li>
      <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 8</li>
      <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 9</li>
      <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 10</li>
       <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 11</li>
       <li><input class="channels" type="checkbox" name="5" value="y">&nbsp;Channel 12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But that would cause problems when you have different no. of children. For example, if there are six then the current selector would remove only the border on the last :)

Comment: This is only work for 5 channel and 3 column count. But not for dynamic one. Sorry for not mentioning my dynamic work.

Comment: in this case we can use :nth-child property for specific children. I don't know about column-count CSS that's why i put this answer.

Comment: As i already choose my answer, but if can you use :nth-child to complete this than i can make you upvote.

Comment: yes. no problem..  i will add more channels and show you how to use.

Comment: look i edited i added 12 channels. To select right corner channel that is from 9 to 12 so i used nth-child(n+9).

Comment: Thanks, But its not dynamic, say if sometime i have only 6 channel and sometime 15 channel than i have change (n+..) right??